# Calculate mean of another column which is filtered from another column

Tags: r, mean

For example, of the 7 columns present one is labelled "Region", the other is an average. I want to find all of the averages of a specific region from the region column and find the mean of them. There is too much data to put here, but say you have Cairns, Brisbane (east) & Brisbane (west) and I would like to find the averages for all Cairns rows and find the mean of those averages, how would I do this?

So far I have changed my data in to a tibble format:

```
QLD.Pokies <- as_tibble(QLD.Pokies)
```

and then grepl filtered for a specific region:

```
QLD.Pokies %>%
   filter(grepl('CAIRNS', Region))
```

**Edit**

```
dataAndWinPEGM <- as_tibble(dataAndWinPEGM)
meanEGM <- dataAndWinPEGM %>%
  filter(grepl('CAIRNS', Region)) %>%
  select(Win.Per.EGM)
meanEGM
mean(meanEGM[["Win.Per.EGM"]])
```

Used the above code to calculate a mean, but not sure if it is working correctly. I can't manually calculate the mean as there are 190+ numbers, any way to check?

Answer (score 1):

without a sample of your data, I can try to show a working example of the `iris` dataset. Also you have to load the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
    
head(iris)
    
iris %>% 
   select(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise(sepal_length_mean = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

From the base set, we select for instance a couple of columns, and then perform a group operation of the sepal length for each specie. Then we take the mean of each group.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    sepal_length_mean
* <fct>                  <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01
2 versicolor              5.94
3 virginica               6.59
```

Hopefully you can apply it to your dataset.